# fix php imagick darker grayscale pngs

Tags: php, imagemagick, png, imagick

When I'm using

```
    $image = new \Imagick();
    $image->readImageBlob( $svgXmlString );
    $image->setImageFormat( "png24" );
    $image->writeImage( $pngFileName );
```

on Imagick Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 it works OK for colored and grayscale images

but

on Imagick Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2013-09-01 it works OK for colored but DARKENS grayscale pictures

Any solution?

Comment: Hi, is there any chance you could upload the example output of both versions, so that they can be added to the Imagick documentation for an example of this issue?

Comment: sure I'll try to do that within the next few days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding

```
// Imagick >= 6.7.6.6 greyscale darker fix
$image->transformImageColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
```

fixes it

Comment: Upgrading ImageMagick to version 6.9.0-1 or later also fixes it.  The behavior you observed is due to confusion about whether grayscale images should be assumed to be linear (gamma==1) or sRGB (gamma approx. 1/2.2).